Counting orbitas for infinite group acting on an infinite set
If an infinite group $G$ acts on an infinite set $X$ with finite stabilizers for every element, then how many orbits could this action have? It seems that smaller stabilizers implies bigger orbits and, since $X$ is the union of its orbits, we will have just a few orbits. But this is just intuition, of course.
By the way, my case of interest is when $X$ is a connected locally finite graph.


how many orbits could this action have?

Arbitrarily many.
Consider $Y=G$ and $G$ acting on $Y$ via multiplication. Then $Y$ has exactly one orbit, and every element has trivial stabilizer.
Now let $X$ be a disjoint union of copies of $Y$. Then every element of $X$ still has trivial stabilizer, but $X$ has as many orbits as copies of $Y$.
